# Gale shapley question about the maximum rounds men can propose

Tags: algorithms

With three men and four women, the maximum number of rounds the algorithm can go with men proposing. please can someone help me with this question

Comment: Could you give some details, or a reference for, for the form of the G-S algorithm you are using?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  "Please help me" alone will not attract a favorable response.  You should add more information to the **body of your question**: what have you tried, how far have you gotten, where are you having trouble?  It's hard to help you if you don't sy what your difficulty is.

Comment: What is a round of proposing by your definition?